# C# CNTK Sparse (and others) using MinibatchSource

Tags: c#, api, cntk, mini-batch

I just started using CNTK C# API and, so far, I have had no problem loading files if I write them in a way that I can read using full matrix readers, e.g., the MNIST tutorial example:

MinibatchSource minibatchSourceExistModel = MinibatchSource.TextFormatMinibatchSource(
                    Path.Combine(ImageDataFolder, "MNIST_test.ctk"), streamConfigurations);

I am confused with sparse data though. It would help to have a C# reference with examples of all possible forms of input to load using the MinibatchSource.

Do I need to save all the zeroes in the file? Is there an example file showing how to write sparse data and load it to use as MinibatchSource input?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I create my .CTF with sparse data like below. It is data with 4 different classes and has a sparse features array where all features included are set to 1

|c 0 0 0 1 |f  3:1  11:1  20:1  23:1  25:1  94:1

|c 0 0 1 0 |f  3:1  5:1  16:1  23:1  25:1 189:1  190:1

The CTF file format is more flexible but this works and I can feed it using the C# API as a minibatchsource.

There are good examples in this document (skip the first part)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/brainscript-cntktextformat-reader

Comment: Yes this works. I guess most of the examples have not made it to the C# api yet

Comment: a few have, see https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/TrainingCSharp